# error Bad Request (400), when I go to the site on the domain

Tags: python, django, nginx, digital-ocean, bad-request

I started the django project on digitalocean.com. The problem is that on my ip address my site is loaded and there are no problems, but if I go through the domain, the "Bad Request error (400)". Domain bought at godaddy.com. Domain settings are correct in accordance with the hosting tutorial https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-point-to-digitalocean-nameservers-from-common-domain-registrars:

```
ns1.digitalocean.com
ns2.digitalocean.com
ns3.digitalocean.com
```

Configuring nginx:

```
upstream bbb_app_server {
  # fail_timeout=0 means we always retry an upstream even if it failed
  # to return a good HTTP response (in case the Unicorn master nukes a
  # single worker for timing out).

  server unix:/webapps/bbb/run/gunicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {

    listen   80;
    server_name example.ru;

    client_max_body_size 4G;

    access_log /webapps/bbb/logs/nginx-access.log;
    error_log /webapps/bbb/logs/nginx-error.log;

    location /static/ {
        alias   /webapps/bbb/static/;
    }

    location /media/ {
        alias   /webapps/bbb/media/;
    }

    location / {
        # an HTTP header important enough to have its own Wikipedia entry:
        #   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Forwarded-For
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;


        # enable this if and only if you use HTTPS, this helps Rack
        # set the proper protocol for doing redirects:
        # proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;

        # pass the Host: header from the client right along so redirects
        # can be set properly within the Rack application
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;

        # we don't want nginx trying to do something clever with
        # redirects, we set the Host: header above already.
        proxy_redirect off;

        # set "proxy_buffering off" *only* for Rainbows! when doing
        # Comet/long-poll stuff.  It's also safe to set if you're
        # using only serving fast clients with Unicorn + nginx.
        # Otherwise you _want_ nginx to buffer responses to slow
        # clients, really.
        # proxy_buffering off;

        # Try to serve static files from nginx, no point in making an
        # *application* server like Unicorn/Rainbows! serve static files.
        if (!-f $request_filename) {
            proxy_pass http://bbb_app_server;
            break;
        }
    }

    # Error pages
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
    location = /500.html {
        root /webapps/bbb/static/;
    }
```

Here are my settings for settings.py:

```
try:
    from .settings_prod import *
except:
    pass
```

Here are my settings for settings_prod.py:

```
    DEBUG = False
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['0.80.00.000',
                 '.example.ru']

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'db1',
        'USER': 'bbb',
        'PASSWORD': 'bbb',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '',
    }
}
```

checked nginx -t:

```
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
```

Comment: if you type the digitalocean ip directly it works?

Comment: Yes, it works fine on ip adress digitalocean.com

Comment: can you share your ip and your domain? it looks like the records are not matching

Comment: Did you check nginx access and errors logs?

Comment: nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you are handling your settings seems to be the problem.

If I understood correctly, you have a **settings.py** and a **settings_prod.py**.

Then, inside the **settings.py**, you are importing all info from **settings_prod.py**.

What I think is happening is, this import happens at the top of the file. Then, probably in the remainder of the **settings.py**, you may have another `ALLOWED_HOSTS`, which is overriding the `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['0.80.00.000', '.example.ru']` defined in your **settings_prod.py**.

If you move the following code:

```
try:
    from .settings_prod import *
except:
    pass
```

To the *bottom* of the **settings.py** file, it will override properly the configurations.

Comment: Yes, you understood me correctly about settings.py and settings_prod.py. But 
`try:
    from .settings_prod import *
except:
    pass` 
is at the bottom of the file settings.py

Comment: change the `DEBUG` to `True` for a moment, restart the Gunicorn process and access the page and see what error you are getting. Or if you have logging properly configured, check Gunicorn's logs.

Comment: In the end, I changed the settings as they were in settings.py and restarted again.